# I want to send a text message from iphone to facebook and twitter

Tags: iphone

I want easy way to send some text messages from iphone to facebook and twitter ?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance...............

Comment: Should be migrated to SuperUser IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the webservice apis from [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) and [twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/). Connect these with your [CellPhone SDK](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) or within a webpage. Dealing with GSM text messages is more complicated.